# bootstrap div doesn't center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a bootstrap site with a central box, but all my container doesn't  center, they stay on left of the page, i don't know why. I just tried with offset, but doesn't work.

[my pen on codepen](http://codepen.io/flipps/pen/dNKmZX)

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1 class="text-center"><span class="title">title</span>
        <i class="fa fa-twitch fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span class="subt">subtitle</span></h1>
      </div>
     
    </div>
     
  </div> <!--close h1 container-->
  
  <div class="container box">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="container status">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col">
      
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Online</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Offline</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">All</button>
</div> <!--btn group--> 
  
        
        
    </div>
    </div>
  </div><!--close container status--> 
    
      </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--container box-->
  
      </div><!--close container fluid-->
```

Comment: Oh man... read Bootstrap documentation (you can't nest container in container for example). And decide what version of Bootstrap you want to use, because in code you use Bootstrap 3 classes and in that Codepen you loaded Bootstrap 4 CSS.

Comment: Ok the problem was the nesting and bootstrap 4 syntax. Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4 uses a slightly different syntax for offsets.

`col-md-offset-3` becomes `offset-md-3`

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRjrwx)

Answer (score 0):

Containers are not nest-able. Use containers in sequence instead.

Use a Bootstrap 4 syntax for offsets if you load Bootstrap 4 CSS. Or load Boostrap 3 CSS.

`offset-md-3`

Boostrap 3 and Bootstrap 4 Docs
http://getbootstrap.com
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com